# How to make individual pull requests vs "stacking" them on top of each other in Github?

Tags: git, github, branch, git-branch, pull-request

I'm not getting anywhere with this... trying to make 2 separate pull requests. Maybe someone can point me to what is wrong. Here is what I'm doing:

Fork repo FOO and clone to my machine

```
 git clone https://github.com/myself/FOO.git
```

Set upstream to track FOO

```
 git remote add upstream https://github.com/maker_of_FOO/FOO.git
```

Create new branch and checkout

```
 git branch FOO_fix_1
 git checkout FOO_Fix_1
```

Edit files and commit and push

```
 git commit
 git push
```

Push new branch to my fork of FOO

```
 git push -u origin FOO_fix_1
```

So far no problem. On Github I can click `Compare and PR`, which then creates the pull request on the `master` branch of `FOO`. My problem starts when I try to make the **second PR**, which should be an individual PR and **not go on top of the first PR**

Create a new branch:

```
 git branch FOO_fix_2
 git checkout FOO_fix_2
 git commit
 git push
 git push -u origin FOO_fix_2
```

This creates the new branch on my remote repo but now when I click `Compare and PR` on Github it compares my
new branch `FOO_fix_2` with `Master` but the PR will just be appended to my first PR.

**Question**:
Is it not possible to make separate PRs on the same `Master` branch of `Foo`? Because I'm fixing two different things in different branches. If everything is stacked back on master why should I bother with creating individual branches on my local version anyway?

Thanks for some clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need checkout the branch you started with in between each bunch of changes

So pull, to get you sync'd up.

checkout master if you aren't on that branch

Create a branch and do your stuff

then checkout master again, will get you back to where you were. So you end up with

```
Master->Branch1
Master->Branch2
```

instead of

```
Master -> Branch1 -> Branch2
```

Comment: ah. explains... trying next time. Thanks!